# One Model with mutiple Forms in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I came to a situation where I need to have 2 different forms one for "new" action and other for "edit" action.

Currently my new action view have

```
  = render 'form'
```

But when I try to create another form for edit

Edit action view

```
  = render 'form2'
```

It doesn't work it return an error message of

ActionView::MissingTemplate in Google_categories_to_masters#edit

Showing C:/master/EDM/app/views/google_categories_to_masters/edit.html.erb where line #3 raised:

Missing partial google_categories_to_masters/form2, application/form2 with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:
  * "C:/master/EDM/app/views"
  * "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/kaminari-0.13.0/app/views"
  * "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.7/app/views"

Can anyone teach me how to can I do in rails application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one form for both new and edit.

In new

```
render 'form'
```

and in edit also

```
render 'form'
```